# How do I change the default Junk Mail folder in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I'm using an IMAP mail service (fastmail.fm) which moves Junk email messages to an IMAP folder called "Junk Mail". Outlook archives Junk to "Junk E-Mail".
How do I change Outlook so that it uses the "Junk Mail" folder for Junk instead of the default?

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to **Configure fastmail.fm** to save probable spam in the `Junk E-Mail` folder Outlook creates than build a custom Outlook configuration.

- Login to fastmail
- Go to `Options > Spam/Virus Protection`
- Click on `Custom` beside `Spam Protection`
- Change the **destination folder for Probable Spam** from `Junk Mail` to `Junk E-Mail` and save.
  [image: Custom Spam Protection Settings]

Answer (score 1):

First, **delete** fastmail's "Junk Mail" folder if it currently exists. Then use the instructions below:

---

Install [Collaboration Data Objects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2714320d-c997-4de1-986f-24f081725d36). (Note that it won't install directly - the file you downloaded just unpacks the real installer. Annoying.)

In Outlook, open the Visual Basic editor: either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, or *Tools* - *Macro* - *Visual Basic Editor*

In the VB window, go to *Tools* - *References*, and enable `CDO 1.2.1` in the list.

On the tree in left side, open *Project1* - *Microsoft Office Outlook* - *ThisOutlookSession*, and paste this script (*[original source](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=831363)*) to the window that opens:

```
Sub CDORenameFolder()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim cdoSession As MAPI.Session
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim cdoFolder As MAPI.folder
    Dim newName As String

    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set cdoSession = New MAPI.Session
    cdoSession.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False

    Set folder = outlookApp.Session.PickFolder()
    Set cdoFolder = cdoSession.GetFolder(folder.EntryID, folder.StoreID)

    newName = InputBox("Rename '" + cdoFolder.Name + "' to:", "Rename folder", cdoFolder.Name)
    If newName <> "" Then
        cdoFolder.Name = newName
        cdoFolder.Update
    End If

    cdoSession.Logoff
    Set cdoSession = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> (or *Run* - *Run Sub*), and run the `ThisOutlookSession.CDORenameFolder` macro. A folder selection window should pop up. Under your IMAP account, choose the "Junk E-mail" folder (the one created by Outlook) and click OK.

(If you get "User-defined type not defined", then you forgot to install and/or activate CDO.)

---

Yes, that is exactly why I hate Outlook now.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly -- you're hard-coding the *destination* folder name into the script, then running the script to pick the *source*?

Comment: @afrazier: My VBScript skills are ... poor. At the time of posting, this is what I had -- copypasta from the Microsoft KB. (It seems I did rewrite the script later; I updated the post.)

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  To be fair to you, if that's what was in the MS KB, that's pretty sad too.

Comment: @afrazier: No, it wasn't - the KB has a sane script with everything hardcoded - for quick renaming of all special folders to their original names. (See "original source" link.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do it, but you could create a rule to move junk mail from the folder where they're placed to the default Junk Mail folder.